From an exception catch block, seems file write is not happening
I want to update a file from the catch block, just a few bytes write. Write() seems to pass, but contents not there. Basically keeping a count of exceptions.
My filesystem is strange one, PJFS in Greenhills Integrity OS using C++14. I tried both std::ofstream, and low level open/write APIs etc, neither worked, did the fsync() as well.  I can read thr file contents from the catch block, but not write.
Appreciate any insights. Thanks.
Both prints look good at the time of Loading and Saving, but after a reboot when I re-load the counter, it has not increased.
     class Tracker
     {
        public:
            void LoadCounter();               // Load counter from file
            void IncrementCounter();          // Save counter++ to file
      
        private:
            static int m_Counter;   //  static counter
            
      };

    // static m_Counter is initialized in Tracker.cpp file
    int Tracker::m_Counter = 0;

    void Tracker::IncrementCounter() 
    {
        std::ofstream file("tracker.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            m_Counter++;
            file << m_Counter;
            file.flush();
            std::cout << "Save: m_Counter is at: " << m_Counter << std::endl;
        } 
    }
    
    void Tracker::LoadCounter() {
            
        std::ifstream file("tracker.txt");
        if (file.is_open()) {
            file >> m_Counter;
            std::cout << "Load: m_Counter is at: " << m_Counter << std::endl;
        } 
    }
    
    void APIwithExceptions()
    {
        throw 0;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        try
        {
            APIwithExceptions();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            
            Tracker memo;
            memo.LoadCounter();      // load counter from file
            memo.IncrementCounter(); // counter++ and saves to file
        }
        
        return 0;
    }


What are you really doing? Can you create a [mre] to show us?

Maybe a stupid question, but is the file marked as read-only or does it perhaps reside on a read-only (mounted) filesystem?

Hi, yeh file is write-able, interestingly enough I tested the Load/Save callls outside the catch block to verify correct load/save behaviors, its only when I do so within the catch block , I am not seen the updated counter value in the file. Since I have a static member in the class, I also moved the memo instantiation out of the catch block, still problem persist.


Why do you use a file to synchronize it? atomic should fit better 1) Please describe whether messages are printed in your test cases. We don't know whether it doesn't work due to failed to open the file or caused by other cases. 2) try if(!file) { std::cout<<stderror(errno);} to print the error. (If it's on filesystem). If it's not the issue of filesystem, you should use <ofs/ifs>.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit) to catch a exception in read/write. 3) You should close the file explicitly.

